# ASP.Net Core MVC : Guest page & Authorized Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an ASP.Net Core MVC application - like banking website.

User should be able to access some of the pages like Home Page, Contacts.. without having to login. But other pages should only be accessible for the authenticated users.

We are using the Azure AD for authentication.

How do I configure the authentication? should I exclude the guest pages (eg: Home Page, Contacts) from authentication using [AllowAnonymous]?

Comment: I am sorry, but you have not put much effort into this question.. This is a very basic implementation of Azure AD authentication (https://dotronald.be/add-azure-active-directory-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-web-application/) and I would rather use [Authorize] attributes on the controllers or action methods where authentication needed instead of the other way around

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, the provided article is for ASP.Net framework. How do I achieve the same in ASP.Net core?

Comment: I am sorry, but your question is not specific enough. There is not much difference between .NET and .NET Core when it comes to this example. Try to implement it and if you run into problems then you ask for help specifically with the issue you have